# Tab order in Visual Studio - Inconsistent between tabs and drop-down

Tags: visual-studio, user-interface

I work more quickly when I accustom myself to the order of my tabs so that I can easily shift between files. Yet in Visual Studio, there is no *one* order of tabs. In the tab view (picture 1), the tabs are ordered chronologically, starting with the most recently opened:

[image]

Yet as soon as the tab view gets filled, one has to use the drop-down on the right to move between files. Confusingly, the ordering of the drop-down is different than the tabs themselves: it is alphabetical! (see below)

[image]

**Is there any way to keep the tab order consistent between the tab view and the drop-down?** This seems like a relatively useful feature.

Ideally I would not want VS to auto-sort *either* of the lists, as I sometimes reorganize them for conceptual clarity. But if this is not possible (so it seems) it would be the next best thing if both views were at least consistent.

Comment: I'd never noticed that before, I agree its annoying.